# Application Shortcut clashing with System shortcut

Tags: macos, shortcut, preferences

I use Figma for UI designing; It has a shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (in Windows) and <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (in Mac) to collapse all the nested groups in the Layers Panel. 
But I am unable to use it in Mac because everytime I press <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, it opens the Launchpad! 
I understand that the shortcut is the same for two actions and the System overrides the application shortcut. 
How can I change the order of preference for this shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcut → Launchpad & Dock → Disable ALT L Shortcut.

Comment: Note, it will presumably be located in the `Launchpad & Dock` pane and keyboard shortcuts as per the above suggestion. You can either disable it or remap the system shortcut to something else.